# running a previous prepared site in joomla in wamp server

Tags: joomla, wamp

I have a site that is designed with joomla . I have run it under wamp . then I have uninstalled wamp server . again I have installed wamp server and installed joomla in it . when I copy and paste my whole site into www folder it dosent work . what I should doing now . 
this is that Error .

Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: La table 'joomla.jdmz0_session' n'existe pas SQL=DELETE FROM `jdmz0_session` WHERE `time` < '1416584979'

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate database also. You are missing jdm0_session table in joomla database.

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall Wampserver, it also uninstalled the databases and tables that belong to them. Joomla as you already know requires a database as all information is stored there, so as well as putting the files/folder back where they were, you also need to set up the database and import your backup of it.